# Different firebase security rules for different apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a firebase project with 2 apps.

1) A android mobile app using firebase authentication.
2) A web app with no authentication functionality.

I want to allow my web app to read and write to any document in firestore, while still enforcing security rules for the users of the mobile app.

Is this possible with firebase security rules or do I need to build authentication functionality for my web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase security rules can't distinguish between apps within a project.  Also, there is no way to distinguish between client platforms.

You should be thinking about ways to authenticate your web app (using Firebase Authentication) so that the authenticated user can read and write only what you allow for that user.